# Add remainder on first count

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, modulo

I need to create a code which needs to assign IDs per person.
The user will input a letter (which will be the ID) then it will be divided into 4.

Example, the user inputs letter A for the ID. IDs will be AA, AB, AC and AD.
Then it will be assigned per person accordingly. The number of persons will also be divided into 4.

And in case there will be a remainder, it will be added to the first persons.

How can I add up the remainder on the first count? Is it possible? Please help

I added a sample illustration.[image]

Comment: Can you show the data in text, i can't see images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
=INT(COUNTA(B3:B1000)/4)+MOD(COUNTA(B3:B1000),4)
```

will give you the `5`, and the following the `4`

```
=INT(COUNTA(B3:B1000)/4)
```

Comment: How can I assign the IDs per quotient? Is there any way?